# Wi-Fi on elementary is such a weak signal

Tags: wifi

When I use Windows 10 I have no problems with the wifi signal and it's quite strong even in my living room. The elementary os isn't picking up the signal or something and it subsequently is very slow or just not working at times. I think it may be a driver issue and I was just wondering where I could find a driver for a realtek wifi adapter.

Comment: Have the same problem on 0.61 with Intel Wireless 8265/8275 and  `iwlwifi` driver. Power management tweaks as described below do not change anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to the Elementary OS forum.  I too noticed signal strength issues with my Razer Blade Stealth (2018). My WiFi hardware is: Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 and the driver: ath10k_pci.

This was the command I used to find that data:

```
lspci -nnk
```

So I followed that command with this:

```
iwconfig
```

The result of that command should show the following line:

```
Power Management:on
```

So, let's disable the WiFi power management.

```
sudo nano /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf
```

change: wifi.powersave = 3
to: wifi.powersave = 2
Exit and save.

Finally, let's make sure your WiFi hardware knows the correct regulatory domain.

```
sudo nano /etc/default/crda
```

change: REGDOMAIN=
to: REGDOMAIN=FCC
Exit and save.
*Note: FCC is the correct entry for Canada, United States and Mexico.  Please enter the correct code for your location.*

Time to **reboot**.

After the reboot re-issue this command:

```
iwconfig
```

The result of that command should show the following line:

```
Power Management:off
```

After the reboot, I've noticed that my WiFi indicator displays full WiFi signal strength like the other devices in the same room.  It is important to note that even if the wingpanel indicator shows less than 100% strength the SSID listing underneath the wingpanel is never less than 100% for this device at this distance from my access point.

Your "mileage" may vary, depending on your wireless gear, surroundings and/or other wireless interference (read: neighbors).

Good luck!

Comment: It's also with noticing that for a lot of Windows installation, the indicator with show 100% when the signal status in the list is far less than.